# Unity Banner is not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

My Banner Ad does show in test mode but without testmode not.
I used a code template from the unity website.
I also asked the unity ads support but they couldn't find the error.
they send me a video of my application,and in this video the banner ad worked.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class newadsystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    // For the purpose of this example, these buttons are for functionality testing:
    [SerializeField] Button _loadBannerButton;
    [SerializeField] Button _showBannerButton;
    [SerializeField] Button _hideBannerButton;

    [SerializeField] BannerPosition _bannerPosition = BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER;

    [SerializeField] public string _androidAdUnitId = "Banner_Android";
    [SerializeField] string _iOsAdUnitId = "Banner_iOS";
    public string _adUnitId = "Banner_Android";

    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize("4395157",false,true);
        // Disable the button until an ad is ready to show:
        _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
        _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;

        // Set the banner position:
        Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(_bannerPosition);

        // Configure the Load Banner button to call the LoadBanner() method when clicked:
        _loadBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadBanner);
        _loadBannerButton.interactable = true;
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Load Banner button is clicked:
    public void LoadBanner()
    {
        // Set up options to notify the SDK of load events:
        BannerLoadOptions options = new BannerLoadOptions
        {
            loadCallback = OnBannerLoaded,
            errorCallback = OnBannerError
        };

        // Load the Ad Unit with banner content:
        Advertisement.Initialize("4395157", false, true);
        Advertisement.Banner.Load(_adUnitId, options);
        Advertisement.Initialize("4395157", false, true);
    }

    // Implement code to execute when the loadCallback event triggers:
    void OnBannerLoaded()
    {
        Debug.Log("Banner loaded");

        // Configure the Show Banner button to call the ShowBannerAd() method when clicked:
        _showBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowBannerAd);
        // Configure the Hide Banner button to call the HideBannerAd() method when clicked:
        _hideBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(HideBannerAd);

        // Enable both buttons:
        _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
        _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;
    }

    // Implement code to execute when the load errorCallback event triggers:
    void OnBannerError(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Banner Error: {message}");
        // Optionally execute additional code, such as attempting to load another ad.
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Show Banner button is clicked:
    void ShowBannerAd()
    {
        // Set up options to notify the SDK of show events:
        BannerOptions options = new BannerOptions
        {
            clickCallback = OnBannerClicked,
            hideCallback = OnBannerHidden,
            showCallback = OnBannerShown
        };

        // Show the loaded Banner Ad Unit:
        Advertisement.Initialize("4395157", false, true);
        Advertisement.Banner.Show(_adUnitId, options);
    }

    // Implement a method to call when the Hide Banner button is clicked:
    void HideBannerAd()
    {
        // Hide the banner:
        Advertisement.Banner.Hide();
    }

    void OnBannerClicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("Banner Clicked!");
    }
    void OnBannerShown()
    {
        Debug.Log("Banner Shown!");
    }
    void OnBannerHidden()
    {
        Debug.Log("Banner Hidden");
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        // Clean up the listeners:
        _loadBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        _showBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        _hideBannerButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
    }
}
```

I looked into the android device log and there was: "Unity   : Banner Error: UnityAds is not initialized."
but i call several times the initialize function.
PS: i am not very good at english.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Start ()`, your code:

```
    Advertisement.Initialize("4395157",false,true);
    // Disable the button until an ad is ready to show:
    _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
    _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;
```

And then at `OnBannerLoaded ()`

```
    // Enable both buttons:
    _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
    _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;
```

But those button are already `interactable = true`.
Maybe you need to change `Start ()` like this:

```
    Advertisement.Initialize("4395157",false,true);
    // Disable the button until an ad is ready to show:
    _showBannerButton.interactable = false;
    _hideBannerButton.interactable = false;
```

**Update 1**
Try to change your code the following way:

```
void Start()
{
    _showBannerButton.interactable = false;
    _hideBannerButton.interactable = false;

    Advertisement.Initialize("4395157",false,true);

    _loadBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(LoadBanner);
    _showBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowBannerAd);
    _hideBannerButton.onClick.AddListener(HideBannerAd);
    _loadBannerButton.interactable = true;
}

public void LoadBanner()
{
       BannerLoadOptions options = new BannerLoadOptions
           {
            loadCallback = OnBannerLoaded,
            errorCallback = OnBannerError
           };
       if (Advertisement.isInitialized) {
            Advertisement.Banner.Load(_adUnitId, options);
           } else Debug.LogWarning ("Adverisement not initialized! Try again later");
}

void OnBannerLoaded() 
{
     Debug.Log("Banner loaded");
     BannerOptions options = new BannerOptions
         {
            clickCallback = OnBannerClicked,
            hideCallback = OnBannerHidden,
            showCallback = OnBannerShown
         };
     Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(_bannerPosition);
            
     _showBannerButton.interactable = true;
     _hideBannerButton.interactable = true;
}

void ShowBannerAd()
{
     Advertisement.Banner.Show(_adUnitId, options);
}
```

Comment: It was at false first but after it doesn't worked i changed it to true to see if that change something but it doesn't

Comment: Is there "Banner loaded" output in the log before "Unity : Banner Error: UnityAds is not initialized."? Is your build a "Development Build"?

Comment: thanks for answereing, no there is no Banner loaded in the log and it is no development build.

Comment: Ok, so it seems you're trying to call something like `Banner.Load()` or `Banner.Show()` before UnityAds is properly initialized. Have a look at the answer above, "Upadate 1" section. Use `isInitialized` and `Debug.Log()` to check if UnityAds is initialized or not.

Comment: ok thanks i will try this

Comment: ok i has tryed it but it dont worked so i looked in the log again and there was this error:
11-05 16:11:23.306 19451  4730 E UnityAds: com.unity3d.services.core.api.Sdk.logError() (line:72) :: No fill for placement Banner_Android
11-05 16:11:23.324 19451  4536 I Unity   : Banner Error: Banner_Android Placement Banner_Android failed to fill!
but there was a bit later this message too:
11-05 16:11:23.854 19451  4536 I Unity   : Banner Error: A Banner is already in use, please call destroy before loading another banner!
but the show banner button was not activated.

Comment: Ok, it would be nice if you upload a minimum functionality project that represents the issue, so we can perform extended debugging.

Comment: By the way, have you tried to integrate UnityAds exactly as shown in this tutorial: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ads@3.2/manual/MonetizationBannerAdsUnity.html

Comment: i did setup the projekt as shown in the tutorial. Here is the basic apk: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dq0Qsinn6m-6KK1lFdy2y4h2n3V5gAkP/view?usp=sharing